# Maven 3: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-archetype

I'm trying to test **maven** using

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook -DartifactId=quickstart -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DpackageName=org.sonatype.mavenbook -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.0 -DinteractiveMode=false
```

After several minutes, the system shows me this:

```
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-catalog/2.2/archetype-catalog-2.2.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-catalog/2.2/archetype-catalog-2.2.pom (2 KB at 4.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-models/2.2/archetype-models-2.2.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-models/2.2/archetype-models-2.2.pom (3 KB at 5.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.8/plexus-utils-1.5.8.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.8/plexus-utils-1.5.8.pom (8 KB at 17.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/2.0.2/plexus-2.0.2.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant-parent/1.8.1/ant-parent-1.8.1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 30:36.874s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 07 15:59:39 BRST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:jar:2.2 (): Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.8: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus:pom:2.0.2 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Read timed out -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Comment: I got an error and this page helped when I ran the OLD maven command to create a project (mvn archetype:create) https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-archetype-plugin-1.0-alpha-7/examples/webapp.html

Answer (score 7):

I too encountered the same problem when I created a project using Idea IDE. Using the below method you can create a stand alone application or a web application without getting any error.

Go to the Terminal. Type below mentioned commands and execute.

**For a web application:**

`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId={project-packaging} -DartifactId={project-name} -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false`

**For a stand alone application:**

`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId={project-packaging} -DartifactId={project-name} -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false`

This will create the project structure by downloading relevant jars etc. When this is done the project structure has been created. Open up an IDE and direct it to created Project`s Pom.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

The error is:

Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.8: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus:pom:2.0.2 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Read timed out
Try again when your network works better (internet connection is better).
Check with ping if you can connect to the http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2.

Answer (score 1):

may be you should try in the root mode ： try with `sudo` + command

Comment: it worked when run with root privilege. so up voted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem when my machine is behind a firewall (corporate network) and I have not set up a proxy in `~/.m2/settings.xml`.

The opposite could also be true, a proxy has been defined, but you're no longer connected to that network.

Details about [Maven's settings.xml can be found here](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/maven-settings/settings.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Maven can't seem to view the plugins, in this case the archetype. This is a network problem. Are you behind a proxy or firewall? If so, follow the instructions given [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html). Otherwise, set your firewall permissions and you can try using sudo too.